# phpMyAdmin/Chrome Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'referrer'

Tags: server, apache2, google-chrome, mysql, phpmyadmin

I tried to access my MySQL-Database via phpMyAdmin but it didn't work. Chrome put the following error in the console:

```
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'referrer'.
```

I could not log into phpMyAdmin, it added some token to my url (common behaviour) but I wasn't able to go further than the login page. It also didn't show any kind of error on the page.

**weird things i noticed**

Normally I access my phpMyAdmin via a Apache Virtual Host that 'answers' my mysql-subdomain. Above mentioned behaviour was noticed when using this subdomain.
But when I use my base-domain/phpmyadin it still shows this error in the console but I can login.

**versions I use**

Chrome: 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Ubuntu: 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-54-generic x86_64)
MySQL-Server (innodb_version): 5.7.26

**tries to fix it**

- reboot machine
- remove phpmyadmin and reinstall it (with `apt-get purge phpmyadmin`)

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. 
The problem does not depend on Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy, but in my case it's a cookie problem.

When I try with firefox or if I browsing in incognito all works fine.

I've solved using in this way.
Open the inspector navigate to Application > Clear Storage > Go ahead and clear everything.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811804/phpmyadmin-failed-to-set-session-cookie-maybe-you-are-using-http-instead-of-htt/54189692#54189692